# label associated to findcontour with opencv

Tags: python, opencv, scikit-image

I have a mask from which I get the contours information using

```
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask.astype('uint8'),cv2.RETR_CCOMP,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
```

How do I get the corresponding label array i.e. an array the same size of mask where values are the indices of contours and located on points of mask which are inside corresponding contours ? I found a way using matplotlib.contains_points function but it is very slow. I'm sure there is another way but strangely I can't find it...here is the version with contains_points :

```
points = np.vstack((Xm.flatten(),Ym.flatten())).T 
labels = -np.ones((mask.shape[0]*mask.shape[1],1))
for ic,contour in enumerate(contours):
    px = contour[:,0,0];
    py = contour[:,0,1];
    p = Path(list(zip(px,py))) # make a polygon
    Inpoints = p.contains_points(points)
    labels[Inpoints] = ic
```

I'm also trying using cv2.connectedComponents but I can't find a way to get the proper indices as connectedComponents is independent from findcontours...EDIT : here is the piece of code:

```
# labels of objects
_, labels_obj = cv2.connectedComponents(mask.astype('uint8'))
labels_obj = labels_obj - 1 # remove background
tmp = np.copy(labels_obj)
for ir,iro in enumerate(reg_objects):
    tmp[labels_obj==ir] = iro + 1
tmp[tmp<0]=0
labels_obj = tmp
# labels of holes present in objects
_, labels_hol = cv2.connectedComponents((1-mask).astype('uint8'))
labels_hol = labels_hol - 2 # remove background (objects are 0 and background is 1 so -2)
tmp = np.copy(labels_hol)
for ir,irh in enumerate(reg_holes):
    tmp[labels_hol==ir] = irh + 1
tmp[tmp<0]=0
labels_hol = tmp
# merge
labels = labels_obj + labels_hol - 1
```

labels is then an array the same size of maks for which values point to the different objects and holes of mask. The problem is that labels==0 will not point to the same object/hole than contours[0] ...
EDIT : the label array is to be used in skimage.measure.regionprops

Comment: perhaps by drawing each contour (drawContours or drawing call for polygons) using a different "color" (index). -- https://xyproblem.info/ what is the goal of all this?

Comment: I want to use the label array in skimage.meausre.regionprops. I don't want to have figures popping up during computation. Regardless I think drawcontours will draw the contours not give me the corresponding label.

Comment: don't worry, opencv's drawing calls don't "pop up figures", they only manipulate arrays. yes, it's somewhat inconvenient that OpenCV doesn't have an API to both label components and give their contours.

Comment: oh ok, noted. So even if I don't have display rights (I run my calculations remotely through ssh) it won't create a problem then ?

Comment: no problem at all. if you don't call namedWindow/imshow/waitKey, no GUI toolkits will be invoked. you might need to watch what package you install. you want one of the `headless` ones (regular xor with contrib), because those don't depend on a GUI library at all. the non-headless ones will... so that might cause GUI stuff to be installed unnecessarily.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I'll make some speed tests right away.

Comment: I can see the utility of this, so I've [opened an issue about it](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/21587). perhaps someone will see it and consider working on it.

Comment: I'll follow closely what comes out of it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, you can create this mask by drawing contours onto a blank image :

```
label_map = np.zeros_like(mask, dtype = 'uint8')
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask.astype('uint8'),cv2.RETR_CCOMP,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

for i, contour in enumerate(contours):
    label_map = cv2.drawContours(label_map, [contour], -1, (255/(i+1)), -1)#draw and fill the contour with color (255/(1+1)).
```

Note that the argument `(255/(i+1))` is only a way of generating a set of `len(contours)` different grayscales, you may change it with a set of colors.

Comment: this choice of label "color" makes the "labels map" nice to display because it uses the full range of brightness. -- for easier calculations, the common choice for label "color" would be simply `i+1` (so `1..N`, 0 reserved for background).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I find strange to go through a graphic solution to get the labels. bwboundaries of matlab gives me the label along the contour with the same function. The goal is not to have a nice image but to use the label array with skimage.measure.regionprops. There is no graphics involved.

Comment: opencv's contours and connected components functions have been around for a long time. nobody (yet?) thought to write a function that does both. I am unfamiliar with the specific choice of algorithms in the implementation. it might be easy to add such code to OpenCV. the bureaucratic hurdles are comparably low.

Comment: I edited my question with the piece of code I built using components. But I have no idea how to make sure the array labels is consistent with contours...

Comment: fair point. if you're lucky, there is some coincidence (if both calls pick the same order for contours and labels)... chances are this will require some more acrobatics...